# How do I access a JSON object's fields in SQL?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I pulled JSON data from a third-party API and I am trying to automate its entry into an SQL database. The format of the JSON is as follows :

```
{ "fields": {
    "Example.FirstName": "Bob",
    "Example.LastName": "Test",
    "Example.Salary": "$50000"
    },
    "UserId": "1001231234"
}
```

I can retrieve the UserId, but anything within fields I am not sure how to access. I figured it would just be fields.Example.FirstName but I keep getting null.
This is what I have done

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max)
SELECT @JSON=BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Python38\Data.JSON', SINGLE_CLOB) as import
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)
WITH
(
    [fields.Example.FirstName] varchar(50),
    [UserId] varchar(50)
)
```

If anyone can explain the syntax of how to access the data in fields, it would be much appreciated.
I am using Microsoft SQL Server if that helps.

Comment: Could you please clearify.
Would you like to add a JSON to a Microsoft SQL Server DB?
Or would you like to store a JSON in Microsoft SQL Server DB and want to know how to access values from it?

Comment: I would like to store JSON data in Microsoft SQL Server (automatically) so I'm in the process of creating a stored procedure to do that. I need to access the values in the fields object to do so. So for example, with how its written now, I'll get [fields.Example.FirstName] = null, but [UserId] will give me a row for each id in the JSON file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select * 
from openjson (@json)
with (
    firstname varchar(50) '$.fields."Example.FirstName"',
    lastname  varchar(50) '$.fields."Example.LastName"',
    salary    varchar(50) '$.fields."Example.Salary"',
    UserId    varchar(50)
)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!